# How to add a RequestBody to a POST request in quarkus REACTIVE ROUTES with RoutingContext?

Tags: java, swagger, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

```
    @Route(path = "/v1/graphql", produces = "application/json", methods = Route.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Uni<Buffer> toHasura(RoutingContext rc, @Body String query) {

        //
    }
```

I'm trying to redirect requests to hasura with my app, but I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter injector found for parameter 1 of route method io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni<io.vertx.mutiny.core.buffer.Buffer> toHasura(io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext rc, java.lang.String query) declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.acme.reactive.routes.ProxyRout, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.acme.reactive.routes.ProxyRout]
```

I've tried to add @Body annotation, the error was gone, but in swagger I still don't see the opportunity to add any body to the request

Comment: May I ask why you are using Reactive Routes instead of RESTEasy Reactive?

Comment: because I need to redirect requests, I'm new to quarkus and it's all very confusing

Comment: If all you need is to redirect users, it's probably easier to use something like https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#using-the-vert-x-web-router with the Router's `reroute` method